# What is tool class? (term from Qt docs)

Tags: c++, qt, class

I was reading [Qt Coding Conventions](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Coding-Conventions)
 and one thing confused me

> Things to avoid:
>
> Do not inherit from template/tool classes

What is tool class?

Comment: Did you also ask the same question here? http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23396

Comment: @Tony yes, it's me, I updated that post as solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with Vahid Farahmand answer, a template class is not the same as a tool class.

The [documentation for QT tool classes](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/examples-tools.html) says:

> Qt is equipped with a range of capable tool classes, from containers
>   and iterators to classes for string handling and manipulation. Other
>   classes provide application infrastructure support, handling plugin
>   loading and managing configuration files.

These are concrete classes designed to perform a particular function. Template classes provide generic types.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's same. Two names for same thing.